# Clearing remote CD cache using Sitecore PowerShell

Tags: powershell, caching, sitecore

I am running publish of a Sitecore item version from PowerShell.
In my specific case I am hiding a version, publish item, then making a version publishable again, and publish an item. The issue is that published content didn't change. When I clear cache manually on CD, the new content appears.

So I am looking for some mechanism to trigger remote cache clearing from CM in between my publishes in the same PowerShell script. For example, the below works from PowerShell to clear cache on CM from CM. But how do I do CD(s) from CM? Need some kind of remote clear cache, or make CDs "think" the the publish was done and cache needs clearing. Web DB content does update after PowerShell script runs, but markup on CDs does not change - need cache clearing.

This is what works on CM from CM in PowerShell.

```
[Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager]::ClearAllCaches()
```

But I need on CD from CM. Please help!!!

Comment: P.S. I do not need a custom remote event, anything out of the box will suffice. So if this article below helps, by all means, use it for your thinking guidance!!!  :) 

https://codeandlearnspot.wordpress.com/2021/10/02/clear-cd-cache-from-cm-custom-remote-event/